# Encoding of JPEG Image with lightning

Tags: camera

I am building a timelapse camera system with the Pi HQ Camera. At night with manual exposure settings of 20 seconds, analogue gain and digital gain settings set, during lightning storms, the image captured seems to have a horrible glow around the over-exposed area. I understand this would be overexposed, but the lines around the edge make for real issues in post production. Does anyone know if this can be fixed in post or in capture?
[image]

Comment: IMHO, this is off-topic for RPi SE as it's more about digital photography than RPi or even the camera. It does appear to be over-exposed - perhaps to the point that the image data has been "washed out", and un-recoverable in post-processing. There is a Photography SE - that might be a better choice?

Comment: Thank you @Seamus - I'm open to feedback on this and I will try. Given this is an issue I've only experienced on my Pi HQ Camera Module and no other digital camera (of which I have shot on dozens), I feel this is a RPi issue. My suspicion is it is directly related to the Sony sensor, but unsure if this is hardware or software.

Comment: You may be right, and I'm only registering my opinion. I'd also like to see you get a good answer, but I'm not sure your chances are the best here. I say that because I **guess** this will ultimately get back to your [EV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_value) being "off" for some reason. Did you get any EV information with the camera?

Comment: I've posed on Photography SE so we will see - thanks for the suggestion. Controls are fully manual and images each image EV is based on the previous image, with coded tolerance to maintain settings for consistent (i.e. non-flickering) timelapse sequences. Here's a little example from a less lightning-loaded shoot: https://www.reddit.com/r/timelapse/comments/nwkd75/days_of_day_to_night_to_day/

Comment: Interesting footage. Do you think it could be down to the [dynamic range of the sensor](https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/dynamic-range.htm)? It would be an interesting experiment to compare footage of the same scene shot with a decent DSLR and the Pi HQ.

Comment: @Seamus thank you - honestly, no idea but it could have something to do with the combination of settings that I'm using with regards to analogue and digital gain settings AND the red / blue gains - it's all low level stuff that I'm pretty new too. I'm pretty sure the camera (sensor) can capture lightning, but it's pretty hard to test without some kinda homemade tesla coil :)

Comment: I guess we're lucky to have a fellow like Nikola Tesla to have come before us, and shown us how to build such a thing :))  So yeah - all of those settings you mention are things that your DSLR takes care of - but with the RPi camera - you are in control!

Answer (score 0):

Issue in this instances was with relation to the analogue and digital gains being too far apart. Changing these to be closer together seems to help the purple / blowout lines.

In follow up shoots, the bright areas are much more evenly over-exposed where you'd expect such blowouts (i.e. from bright lights in dark settings, or lightning).